# capturing datatable from gridview datasource that is using stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datasource

I have a Gridview that uses a stored procedure as its datasource. How can I load the results into a datatable?

It seems like any event that I try returns Nothing.

```
Dim dt As DataTable = GridView1.DataSource
```

trying this after the Gridview has been populated. Like in the OnSorting event.

UPDATE:

ASP:

```
asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="itemDataSource"
```

In a DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged event I fire this code...

vb.net

```
    itemDataSource.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnectionString").ToString()

    itemDataSource.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure
    itemDataSource.SelectCommand = "usp_showPendbyDB"
```

the above itemDataSource is bound to my Gridview.

I have tried to then capture the datasource back to a session in multiple events as I have stated...

```
        Session("grdvTable") = GridView1.DataSource
```

No matter where I place this, it always equals Nothing.

**SOLUTION**: In addition to the marked answer below, in order to rebind the data table to the Gridview I had to remove the DataSourceID from the Gridview and bind to the Gridview in the code behind.

VB.net

```
    GridView1.DataSource = itemDataSource
    GridView1.DataBind()
```

also, after sorting or other data manipulation on the data table just apply the same code with the update data table results.

```
    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()
```

Of course if you need to manage writes back to the database other code will be needed, I was just sorting on various col headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On postback your datasource will be empty.  See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx

Try this:

```
Dim dv as DataView = itemDataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
Dim dt as DataTable = new DataTable()
dt = dv.ToTable()
```

Comment: I believe this was kind of my point. I have tried a number of events including a Dropdown click event. Just need to capture the data from the gridview.

Comment: Just like the example shows you need to cache the datasource in the session or requery the database whenever you post back. i.e. in your click events

Comment: I guess that is what I am trying to say, I have tried to cache the datasource, it equals Nothing every time/place I try to assign it to a session variable. Could you provide a code sample and location of where it needs to reside?

Comment: Post the relevant code so I can see what's happening.

Comment: Updated OP to show the snippet that populates the bound Gridview.

Comment: Where do you set the datasource and bind the GridView1?

Comment: The Gridview's datasource is set to this itemdatasource, added to OP.

Comment: Are you using something like this on your asp page?  <asp:SqlDataSource id="myDataSource".../>  Then reference this in your codebehind.

Comment: Yes but just this....<asp:SqlDataSource ID="itemDataSource" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>

Comment: See my updated answer on how to convert itemDataSource to a DataTable

Comment: thanks for that I think I got it, perhaps a new question, how can I update the Gridview after a sort. Basically same code in the opposite direction?

Comment: @htm11h For sorting, i would open another question.

Comment: I already have the sorting I just need to bind it back to the Gridview.

Comment: According to this, it should just work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110478/asp-net-trying-to-implement-sortparametername-property-to-sqldatasource

Comment: Well a little further reading indicated that the solution marked as the answer does not work. But it did provide the insight to solve my sort issue. I am updating the OP with the full solution. thanks again.